# Updating the Sheet content causes break in links between another sheets

Tags: excel, reference, calculation

Using the statistical programming language R, I recreated/updated one sheet in the whole workbook, keeping the same name of the worksheet. After successful execution und update of values, the connection between the newly created/updated sheet and the rest of the workbook's sheets get lost. Though, in the formulas I can always clearly see the correct reference to the newly created/updated sheet, but the formulas are working only after clicking and entering each of them separatly. The option "calculation automaticly" doesn't work. I tried also calculate sheet or calculate workbook. Neither of these options worked. Only manually I can activate the formulas.

Any kind of help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could figure out a way to recheck all formula dependencies. It was quite easy. You should use the following combination: CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + F9